# How to create alert in Oracle Forms builder after Save the form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

When I 'Save' without using any button how to create an alert on Oracle Forms Builder

For example: On delete button, I have created an alert. Where should I change in below code for Control +'S' pressed.

```
`DECLARE
   v_delete       NUMBER;
   l_item_id      NUMBER;
   l_subwork_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   GO_BLOCK ('WORK_MATERIAL_REQE_V');
   l_item_id := :WORK_MATERIAL_REQE_V.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID;
   l_subwork_id := :WORK_MATERIAL_REQE_V.SUB_WORK_DESCRIPTION_ID;

   IF :WORK_MATERIAL_REQE_V.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      SET_ALERT_PROPERTY ('alt_delete',
                          alert_message_text,
                          'Do You Want to Delete?');
      V_DELETE := SHOW_ALERT ('alt_delete');

      IF V_DELETE = alert_button1
      THEN
         DELETE FROM WORK_MATERIAL_REQE pbl
               WHERE     INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = l_item_id
                     AND SUB_WORK_DESCRIPTION_ID = l_subwork_id;

         COMMIT;
         DELETE_RECORD;
         COMMIT;
         CLEAR_BLOCK (no_validate);
         GO_BLOCK ('WORK_MATERIAL_REQE_V');
         EXECUTE_QUERY;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What's **on delete** button ? Btw, **F10** is the default key for committing within the Oracle Forms, but not **Ctrl +S** .

Comment: I have tried it previously  for an delete button. It properly executed. Now I have done it with Ctrl+ S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I change in below code for Control +'S' pressed

This is the `KEY-COMMIT` form-level trigger.

Comment: I have used it in POST-FORMS-COMMIT. Got the result.